# Ошибка при обработке фрейма. Неправильный тип данных

Tags: r

Имеются данные (файл Data_projects).
По условиям задания необходимо провести ряд действий со столбцом "Distance".

Делаю:

> mean(data$Distance)

Получаю:

> Warning message in mean.default(data$Distance): "argument is not
>   numeric or logical: returning NA"

Делаю:

> median(data$Distance)

Получаю:

> Error in median.default(data$Distance): need numeric data Traceback:
>   1. median(data$Distance)
>   2. median.default(data$Distance)
>   3. stop("need numeric data")

Что не так с командами/форматом данных?

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему в столбце *data$Distance* у вас присутвуют пропущенные данные, т.е. **NA**, что бы их отбросить при расчёте среднего используйте аргумент `na.rm = TRUE`.

`mean( data$Distance, na.rm = TRUE)`

По умолчанию `mean()` не умеет обрабатываеть **NA**.

Comment: In mean.default(data2$Distance, na.rm = TRUE) :

  аргумент не является числовым или логическим: возвращаю NA

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, что вернёт в вашем случае функция `str(data2)` ?

Comment: Как вариант у вас этот столбец имеет не числовой тип данных, тогда попробуйте `mean( as.numeric(data$Distance), na.rm = TRUE )`.

Comment: str(data2)
...
$ Distance       : Factor w/ 79 levels "1004,78676794652",..: 69 25 5 45 9 26 36 62 31 58 ...
...

Comment: as.numeric
>40
Только я  не пойму как это работает. В исходном документе оч.длинные циферные значения.

Comment: `str(data2) ... $ Distance : Factor w/ 79 levels`, говорит о том, что тип данных в этом поле у вас *factor*, это не числовой тип данных. Поэтому вам изначально надо привести его к числовому типу через `as.numeric()`, и уже потом считать среднее через `mean( na.rm = TRUE )`.